# Find the probability that one of the buses will arrive within two minutes.

Tags: probability

The teacher gave me the following task:

> Bus 57 arrives at the stop every 4 minutes, and bus 60 arrives every 6
> minutes. The interval between the 57 and the next 60 does not exceed 4
> minutes. Find the probability that one of the buses will arrive within
> two minutes.

I tried to solve the problem with intervals graphically:
[interval graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33ymQ.png)

The figure shows two intervals [0.4] and [0.6] (marked in red), this rectangle is the probability that either bus will arrive at any time, hence the probability is one. I then subtracted from the rectangle the probability that the bus will arrive in two minutes (marked in blue). I then calculated the area of the resulting figure = 16, so the probability that any of the buses will arrive in 2 minutes is 16/24 = 2/3.

But this answer is wrong, because I did not take into account that the interval between the 57th bus and the next 60th bus does not exceed 4 minutes. How do I calculate the probability taking this into account?

(The 57 and 60 are just bus names).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what the question means by "the interval between the 57 and the next 60 does not exceed $4$ minutes". But assuming it means "the interval between the **next** 57 and the next 60 does not exceed $4$ minutes", this excludes a triangular portion of your diagram with vertices $(4,0)$, $(6,0)$ and $(6,2)$: this is where the next 57 arrives more than $4$ minutes before the next 60 (it's not possible for the 60 to arrive more than $4$ minutes before the 57, since a 57 will always arrive within $4$ minutes).

So the area of the pink region of your diagram is reduced by $2$, and the blue region is unchanged.

Comment: By "the interval between the 57 and the next 60 does not exceed 4 minutes" question means that interval between 57th bus and following it 60th bus does not exceed 4 minutes, if it makes more sense. I'm assuming you got it right, but could you clarify why it's a triangular area? Is it because the more time that has elapsed since the last 57 bus arrived, the more likely it is to arrive in the given two minutes?

Comment: @Krip I assume in your diagram the point $(x,y)$ corresponds to the possibility that a 57 will arrive in $y$ minutes time and a 60 will arrive in $x$ minutes time. In this case we're told $x\leq y+4$, so we cut off a corner along the line $y=x-4$.

Comment: This makes it less likely that a bus will arrive within $2$ minutes - the cases we exclude have a 57 arriving within this time.